# Predict time series classes 15 min before

Tags: time-series, lstm

I have multivariate time-series as input and I need to predict an event ("active" or "inactive"). The occurrence of class needs to be predicted (at least) 15 minutes before it occurs, so that take appropriate action can be taken to avoid that event, kind of fault prediction.

So, the difference with classic time-series classification problems, is that I need the prediction of the time-series class to be done in advance. How could I do this?

This is sample dataset:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Data Science SE community. What do you mean by the classes here, are you trying to forecast values for different classes (individual timeseries ) 15 mins in the future.? In order to better understand the problem, it will be good to have a look at the dataset as well any approaches you have taken.

Comment: I added the sample dataset, pls have look